# Data collected from ROS

Tags: lidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can we collect the flight data after a ROS simulation and what kind of dataset do we obtain? Can we get the sensor and video dataset with timestamps to be used in analysis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348304/data-collected-from-ros/) by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-03**:
I can't answer this (as I'm not into drones), but I would recommend to add quite some more details and information to your question, as right now your question lacks all context. *What* exactly are you using? Which packages? What tools are you using for simulation?

Or if you're asking this to determine whether you should even (want to) use ROS: please tell people here what it is you're using right now, and what sort of functionality you are looking for.

Without more context I believe the best answers you are going to get will be similar to:

"well, if you use the correct packages and configuration for them, you could do that".

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-03**:
Hector, Gazeboo or any other package to be used with drones are all ok. Actually I am new into the ROS and just trying to run it. How does the data collection process happen when I fly a drone for a few minutes? Where can I find the resulting data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can record any ROS data you want using `rosbag record`:  http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline

Then you can play that data back later.  While playing back recorded data, it looks basically like it did originally, so you can use any tools and utilities you want to look at and analyze the playback data.  Same as you could do with the live data.

All ROS data has timestamps, I believe. I think you get that for free with ROS.  But some sensor plugins might also embed their own special timing information into the streaming data if they feel it necessary.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2020-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-04**:
Thank you very much. I will try after running the system.

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-09**:
Thank you Kurt. rosbag record was helpful. This link helped me with recording the data:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Rec...

now I need to reduce the size of data downloaded as it is a huge amount in a short period of time. Should I change the sampling rate of sensors and fps of the cameras or would there be any other way?

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-09**:
This question can be continued from https://answers.ros.org/question/348942/sensor-data-too-huge/